# Can I get current sleeping state via Sony Lifelog API?

Tags: sony, sony-lifelog-api

I need to get the current state from my SmartBand SWR12 - if I am asleep or awake.

In the example on the Sony developers site I see that I can get per-minute report of this state with the options "awake", "light" and "deep". Here is this link: 
https://developer.sony.com/develop/services/lifelog-api/endpoints/activities/#sleepActivityType

But when I try to test it in API Explorer I get only empty responses for the last minute (even not only the last one minute, but also the last 3, 5, 10, etc.).
Is it possible? And if it is, how can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: That does sound strange. Can you post the query you are trying here? So you are saying that the data skips minutes? Can you post a small set of results showing what the skip looks like?

Comment: Well, I try anything like this in the API Explorer:
https://apigateway.lifelog.sonymobile.com/v1/users/me/activities?start_time=2016-04-03T15%3A00%3A00.000Z&end_time=2016-04-03T16%3A00%3A00.000Z&type=sleep
but always get empty response:
{
  "result": []
}

Comment: One thing to do might be checking to be sure that the account you are using to record data is the same account you are using to access data using the API Explorer. After you have confirmed that the accounts are the same can you try running this query to see if you get any sleep data at all: https://apigateway.lifelog.sonymobile.com/v1/users/me/activities?type=sleep

Comment: Yes, the account is the same.
And i see that this query shows me only periods of sleep: "light" and 'deep". No "awake" state like in the example in the documentation. So I think that if I run my query using the period when I didn't sleep I'll get empty response, no "awake", is it right?

Comment: ok I see. The query I sent you should have given you everything that the API was tracking as far as sleep goes. Let me investigate on  my side and see if I can find a better answer.

Comment: Thanks! My main need is to get from the API my current state - awake or asleep. Tell me please the query that will give me such response.

Comment: Hi Robert, did you investigate my question? How can I get my current state?

Comment: Hi Alexander. I have been checking with the development team for an answer. They are looking in to the issue now and I will let you know as soon as I hear something.

Comment: Hi Alexander. Sorry for the delay in getting back to you. It seems that there is in fact an issue retrieving awake data from the SWR12 so for now you will not be able to pull awake data using that device. Please let me know if you have more questions about this.